# How to make a C code to fetch some content from the internet?

Tags: c

Suppose I want my C code to fetch the headline from a website, like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

How to do that?

Can I write a program in C to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an existing HTTP library, for example [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/). If you are using some framework, maybe it already has a HTTP client.

Answer (score 5):

Read the [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

> This is a beginner's guide to socket
>   programming with Internet sockets. It
>   is meant to be a springboard that will
>   launch you into the exciting world of
>   TCP/IP programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to get your result, but the simple way would be to use a library since parsing html is often complicated.

You could try to use [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/)

There is also [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which allows you to simulate a browser.

But trying to parse html yourself will be.... painful..